# Insert into array at multiples of a value, where value increments in between array passes

Tags: arrays, algorithm, indexing, merge, insert

I have a base array and an arbitrary number of arrays - not *actually* arrays, but values calculated in order (more on this in the end). I would like to insert the newly calculated values in front of the base array values.

The language I am using has dynamic arrays, and has a method called `insert`, that inserts the value in the specified index.

```
arr = [0, 1, 2]

// insert `9` in index `0`
arr.insert( 0, 9 )

// result
// [9, 0, 1, 2]

// insert `8` in index `2`
arr.insert( 2, 8 )

// result
// [9, 0, 8, 1, 2]
```

Visualising the question:

The base array is made of `o`, and new values are `a`, `b` etc.

```
// values

o o o o o
a a a a a
b b b b b
c c c c c
d d d d d
e e e e e


// desired result in the end of each value calculation loop

o     o     o     o     o
oa    oa    oa    oa    oa  
oab   oab   oab   oab   oab 
oabc  oabc  oabc  oabc  oabc
```

Step by step (loop) insertion visualistion

```
o     o     o     o     o

// insert( 1, a )
oa    o     o     o     o

// insert( 3, a )
oa    oa    o     o     o

// insert( 5, a )
oa    oa    oa    o     o

// insert( 7, a )
oa    oa    oa    oa    o

// insert( 9, a )
oa    oa    oa    oa    oa

// insert( 2, b )
oab   oa    oa    oa    oa

// insert( 5, b )
oab   oab   oa    oa    oa

// insert( 8, b )
oab   oab   oab   oa    oa

// insert( 11, b )
oab   oab   oab   oab   oa
.
.
.
```

How it actually looks in code:

```
for( j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
{
    for( i = 0; i < baseArrLength; i++ )
    {
        idx = (j+1) + (i * (j+2));

        base.insert( idx, val );
    }
}
```

The first loop determines the 'type-amount' of new values to add. Speaking in the previously stated letter form, when `j == 0`, calculate and insert `a` values; when `j == 1`, do `b`, etc.

The second loop does the calculations, and should preferably insert the calculated values in the base array (the main problem).

`i*2+1` works for the first loop (`a`), but I'm not sure how to modify it to fit for the rest. How do I determine the `idx` to insert?

Am I doing wrong by thinking with `insert`?

Edit: Test snippet:

Desired output:
`o a b c d o a b c d o a b c d o a b c d o a b c d`

```
function test()
{
    base = ["o","o","o","o","o"];

    baseLength = 5;

    for( j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
    {
        for( i = 0; i < baseLength; i++ )
        {
            // the problem
            idx = (j+1) + (i * (j+2));

            // "a" or "b"...
            val = GetVal(j);

            base.insert( idx, val );
        }
    }

    for( i = 0; i < base.len(); i++ )
    {
        print( base[i] + " " );
    }
}

function GetVal(j)
{
    switch(j)
    {
        case 0: return "a";
        case 1: return "b";
        case 2: return "c";
        case 3: return "d";
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like "language I am using" is `Java`?

Comment: Add the code into your snippet here that sets `val` so we can see that.

Comment: @cellepo The value of `val` and the language are irrelevant, because this is an alghorithmic question.

Comment: This question being asked with included code snippets made the language relevant.  I'm not sure why its so important to hide what language the snippets are written in here, since the snippets themselves are.  Language is also relevant because if someone is who isn't familiar with the language used here is trying to understand the question, it might not be immediately obvious to them which language they should refer to for the syntax they aren't familiar with (i.e: "to figure out that `case` thing from the code, should I Google "case" with "Python", or "Java", or...").

Comment: I agree this question is mostly algorithmic, but because of that, it would have been better Asked on https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't know how to use SO, I only know how to read it. And the only time I needed help, I figured it out myself after asking it...


I tried to keep the snippet syntax as simple and C-like as possible. I don't know what languages there are with this switch-case syntax, I would think that it was obvious what it does - returning values depending on the input. I also didn't want to state the language so the answer I get is purely algorithmic and not dependant on any language feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the formula same day of asking the question. It is

`(i+2) + (j * (i+2))`

where `i` is the outer loop, and `j` is inner.

Answer (score 0):

Your `idx` logic was wrong.

```
// Loop 10 times
for(int j = 1; j < 11; j++){
    String val;
    // TODO: val becomes set from some calculation the Questioner does

    int idx = j;
    for(int i = 0; i < baseArrLength; i++){
        idx = idx + j + 1;
        base.insert(idx, val);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added a test snippet I used in the original post. Using your answer, I get this output: 

`o o o b o c b d o c b d o c b d o c b d o c o d `